# How to resolve "fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019, cmath

I am as new to C++ as someone can be. I have been given the task of installing a simulation, but I keep running into error codes. I was able to resolve most of them, but there is one I am not sure how to tackle.

The error code is `C2668`, and its description is:

> "fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Project is "Run Simulation" and File is `corecrt_math.h` on line 415.

Honestly, I'm not sure if any of the information I have given is of any use, and I'm not sure what information to provide. Maybe it would be better if you could ask me some questions and I can answer them to the best of my ability?

I have included a screenshot of my Visual Studio 19:

[image: Visual Studio]

<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Reproducible example ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vcRTjo))

```cpp
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    std::isnan(1);
}
```

Expected outcome: That it compiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably fed `std::fpclassify` an integer somehow. Visual Studio has an issue with the integer overloads for the `<cmath>` functions that manifests itself like in your case instead of casting the integer to a `double` in accordance with:

[c.math.syn#2.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmath.syn#2.2):

> […] if any argument of arithmetic type corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` **or an integer type**, then all arguments of arithmetic type corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `double`.

I wrote an [error report for `std::signbit`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/923187/stdsignbit-misses-overloads-for-integer-types.html)  but it's the same for all `<cmath>` functions that I've tested and `std::fpclassify` is one of them - and it's used internally by many other `cmath` functions.

Line 415 in `corecrt_math.h` is within the **`isnan`** function which calls `fpclassify` internally.

Steps to fix the problem:

- When you build your project you'll get a list of errors in the *Error List* box. Look for lines showing `see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan<int>(_Ty) noexcept' being compiled` or similar. The `<int>` part may be any integer type.
- Double click that line and the IDE should place the cursor on the call to `isnan` that is made with an integer.
- Replace the `isnan(`*`integer`*`)` call with `isnan(static_cast<double>(`*`integer`*`))`.
- Repeat these steps for any other `cmath` functions causing problems.

Note: Using `isnan` with integers is pointless. `isnan(`*`integer`*`)` will always return `false` so a compiler with optimization turned on should replace the whole call with `false`.

Comment: I worked perfectly!!!!!!!! I appreciate you help so much, especially because I don't know much of this and you were willing to help me take baby steps. Again I thank you for your time and I hope you have a good night! Now those errors are gone, I have a new Linker error... lol I guess I'll have to spend some time trying to resolve that as well. Thanks again!