# "fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks, cmath

I have a very similar problem to this one: [How to resolve "fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646166/how-to-resolve-fpclassify-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function)

I have a large project with about 100 cpp-files and 100 header-files that work fine in Codeblocks using GNU GCC compiler, but I want to migrate the project to VS19. It seems to work fine except for one error: `"fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function`

The error list in VS19 tells me it is located in `corecrt_math.h` on a return value at line 415:

```
template <class _Ty>
_Check_return_ inline bool isnan(_In_ _Ty _X) throw()
{
    return fpclassify(_X) == FP_NAN;
}
```

When looking into my code I see that I use `std::isna` in 13 files, 24 locations (the error list does not refer to these places at all). However, unlike the problem that I linked to above, I do not see that I check if an `int` is `na` anywhere. Instead I have cases like this:

```
if (std::isnan(static_cast<double> (min)) && std::isnan(static_cast<double> (max)))
    simulation_error("Error: No limits");
```

Where `min`and `max` are defined as `const double & min = NAN` and `const double & max = NAN` (`min` and `max` are set in the constructor).

Do you have any idea on how to find the error and how to solve it? I tried many hours yesterday - without any success.

Edit:

Full error message below:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(415,1): error C2668: 'fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(300,31): message : could be 'int fpclassify(long double) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(295,31): message : or       'int fpclassify(double) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(290,31): message : or       'int fpclassify(float) noexcept'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt_math.h(415,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\Name\Documents\C++\Project name\Project name\src\module.cpp(668): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan<bool>(_Ty) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=bool
1>        ]
```

Which refers to:

```
std::vector<double> stoprule_rel;,

if (!(std::isnan(static_cast<double> (stoprule_rel[i])
```

Comment: Are you sure the error messages don't contain references to your own code? Take a look at the compiler output, not just VS one-line summary. The compiler should tell you for which type `_Ty` the template is instantiated.

Comment: Hm, maybe it is in this: `std::vector<double> stoprule_rel;`, `if (!(std::isnan(static_cast<double> (stoprule_rel[i]) `

Can't I write like above?

Comment: What is `_Ty` reported by the compiler?

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: I have posted it now, did not know you got more info there than in the error list.

Comment: The line is incomplete. Most probably you're doing something like this: `std::isnan(static_cast<double>(min) && std::isnan ...)`, that is, you misplaced one `)` and invoke `std::nan` on `bool`. Double check parentheses.

Comment: That seems to have been the case! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message like `fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function` is always accompanied by **notes**. For example, for a simple program

```
#include <cmath>
int main() {
    std::isnan(5);
}
```

VS [complains](https://godbolt.org/z/GxRkIf):

```
corecrt_math.h(415): error C2668: 'fpclassify': ambiguous call to overloaded function
corecrt_math.h(300): note: could be 'int fpclassify(long double) throw()'
corecrt_math.h(295): note: or       'int fpclassify(double) throw()'
corecrt_math.h(290): note: or       'int fpclassify(float) throw()'
corecrt_math.h(415): note: while trying to match the argument list '(_Ty)'
        with [ _Ty=int ]
<source>(3): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool isnan<int>(_Ty) throw()' being compiled
        with [ _Ty=int ]
```

From these notes we can infer that `_Ty` is `int` and that `std::nan` was called on the line 3 of our source code. Take a look at the full compiler output for your compilation, it will tell you the exact place in your code where the error is triggered.